# How to do a combination search for clicking a ink Cypabara Rspec

Tags: rspec, hyperlink, click, capybara

```
describe 'Destroy Student Record' do
        it 'should allow to Delete My student', js: true do
          expect {
            find('.icon-delete',"a[href ='/room/grade3/#{@student.id}']").click
            page.find('.btn.delete', text: 'Sure').click
          }.to change(Student, :count).by(-1)
        end
      end
```

but the problem is that when their are 2 records it shows .icon-delete is ambiguous and also href is same for delete and view details so for href also it show ambiguous.
How can i do a combination search

Comment: find doesn't take 2 strings - show the actual HTML you're trying to click

Comment: <a href="/room/grade3/10036" class="btn" title="Delete"><i class="icon-delete"></i></a>

Answer (score 2):

With the HTML

```
<a href="/room/grade3/10036" class="btn" title="Delete">
  <i class="icon-delete"></i>
</a>
```

there are multiple ways to click -  click_link will match on the id, text, or title of the link so to just click on the link you could do

```
click_link('Delete', href: "/room/grade3/#{@student.id}")
```

If you need to click specifically on the <i> element you could do either of

```
find_link('Delete', href: "/room/grade3/#{@student.id}").find('.icon-delete').click
find("a[href ='/room/grade3/#{@student.id}'] i.icon-delete").click
```

Note: even with these fixes your test will probably fail.  That's because you're using the `change` matcher and your block isn't doing anything to make sure the action has completed before the change matcher checks the Student count again.  This is because when using any of the JS supporting drivers `click` just clicks the button, it doesn't know about any side effects to wait for, and returns to the test while the app goes off and starts to process whatever behavior the click triggers.  To fix that your test would need to be something like

```
expect {
  ... Do whatever clicking of link/button ...
  expect(page).to have_text("Student deleted") # whatever message is shown once the student is actually deleted or an assertion for other visible change
}.to change(Student, :count).by(-1)
```

This way the code will delay until the student is actually deleted and the `change` matcher can get the Student count again.